# Steps or Procedure to create and authenticate web SDK

Tags: authentication, oauth, sdk, rsa, oauth-1.0a

I tried searching in various places, googling about how I can create and authenticate an SDK which I can use as a starting point. Here is what I am trying to achieve.

**My Application:**
I am creating a saas similar to firebase, supabase etc., where a user signs up on my application and adds some data, say a todo list.

Now, I would have to provide a client SDK(javascript) and server SDK(python, nodejs). Using this the customer should be able to add the SDK to his own application (**Customer Application**) and be able to access the data that **My Application** provides.

To do this, when the SDK is used in the **Customer Application**, I need to authenticate and get the user details, roles and provide the data from **My Application**. How can I do this?

I have seen that there is some kind of `Client key` and `Server key` generated in **My Application**. These keys can be used by the customer in his application and initialize the sdk using the `Client key`.

1. What kind of auth mechanism is this
2. How is the `Client key` and `Server key` generated securely

Any link/pointers to resources will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We use JWT based auth that encode certain Postgres user roles. You can find more information on it here: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api#api-security

Comment: Answers should be self contained. Do not rely on external resources.